# How to count patterns in multiple files using awk

Tags: awk, file-processing

I have multiple log files and I need to count the number of occurrences of certain patterns in all those files.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
match($0,/New connection from user \[[a-z_]*\] for company \[([a-z_]*)\]/, a) 
{instance[a[1]]++}

END {
 for(i in instance)
 print i":"instance[i]
}
```

I am running this script like this:

```
awk -f script *
```

But it looks like count is not correct. Is my above approach correct to handle multiple files?

Comment: The approach seems sound as such. Can you add some simple test data with the actual result you get and the correct result you expect? Please [edit] your question to update it.

Comment: @tripleee My question is, whether the value of `instance` will be retained while parsing multiple files?

Comment: Found the issue: I missed `A-Z` in the regex and hence entries with capital letters were missing

Answer (score 0):

try moving the curly brace up to the same line as the `match` function. Otherwise the `instance[a[1]]++` will occur for every line. Doesn't it also print out the full line of every match too, to start? The `match` will have a default action of `{print}` when on its own line.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

match($0,/pattern/, a) {
    instance[a[1]]++
}

END {
 for(i in instance)
 print i":"instance[i]
}
```

Further details of how individual file names are read is available [at the GNU site](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Other-Arguments.html#Other-Arguments) but applicable generally. `BEGIN` is before any files have been read, `END` is after all, and variables stay the same, apart from a few built in (`FNR` for example, record number for this file).